# Fast insertion of values into a map with an increasing integer as the key?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Efficiency of the `map::insert(iterator position, const value& k)` can be dramatically improved by providing the appropriate value in parameter position.

If I use integer numbers as the key, and every insertion is done with a number larger than all previously inserted keys, can I speed up the `::insert` operation when giving the `::end()` iterator of the map?

Something like:

```
myMap.insert( myMap.end() , make_pair( next_number , myValue ) );
```

where `myMap` is of type `map<uint64_t,MyType>` and `next_number` is an every incrementing large integer.

Edit:

The answer to this question might differ depending on whether the data stored in the `map` is dense or not (see discussion below). So, lets ask the question in both ways: Once it's dense once it's not. Still curious. Perhaps measuring will answer it.

Comment: Exactly. In the case that the key is `uint64_t` and always increasing, is it the "best hint" to give `::end()` as the hint?

Comment: I'd wager that `insert` requires a dereferenceable iterator (which `end()` is not), but I'm not absolutely certain about that.

Comment: @eq-: No, the position iterator just has to be a valid iterator, not a dereferenceable one. And, since the idea is that it's a position that your new element most likely precedes, it would be kind of useless if it didn't allow end().

Comment: If you're concerned about insertion performance, why not use `unordered_map<>` instead of `map<>`?

Comment: The standard doesn't mandate any difference whatsoever. So this is a micro-optimization question, which you can only resolve by actual testing. In a quick test, I found that inserting a ton of elements in order took almost the exact same amount of time either way, and more time was spent in allocating new chunks of memory than anywhere else—but your platform may be different.

Comment: @abarnert I think C++11 actually changed on which side of "hint" the inserted value was hinted to be applicable (i.e. pre-C++11 hint was to precede the new value).

Comment: @abarnet I do a lot of insertions, and deletions. On average only two handful remain stored in the container.

Comment: @eq- Just checked the specs. The hint does not need to be dereferenceable (in C++03 or C++11), but you're right about the order changing between C++03 and C++11.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I stand corrected. Good to clear that one.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: Actually, it looks like you're right about the order changing, but you've got it backward. In C++11, the complexity is "logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if t is inserted right before p", and "t is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to p", so it should be end(), while in C++03 it's "amortized constant if t is inserted right after p", and "p is a hint pointing to where the insert should start to search", so it should be --end(). And that's apparently why they made the change, so end() would make sense. But still, +1 for raising the issue.

Comment: @Frank: So? Explaining your use case to use still doesn't allow us to guess how much the optimization will help you. The only way to find that out is to actually measure.

Comment: If you're going to insert so the data always goes at the end, why not just use an `std::vector` with `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound` to do your searching? With most modern processors, you can pretty much count on this being quite a bit faster than `std::map`. If your keys are consecutive (not just increasing) integers, you can index into it in O(1) instead of an O(log N) binary search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer the question asked, the C++ specs say that:

- In C++03, insertion into a map with `a.insert(p,t)` must be amortized constant complexity (rather than logarithmic) if `t` is inserted right *after* `p`.
- In C++11, insertion into a map with `a.insert(p,t)` must be amortized constant complexity if `t` is inserted right *before* `p`.

and in neither case does `p` need to be dereferenceable. Therefore, in your case, `a.end()` is likely to be the best hint in C++11, but not in C++03.

Comment: That's a twisted situation. Do i get the worst possible if i put the hint just one position to the right of the best hint?

Comment: @Frank : You could always decrement conditionally based on the value of the `__cplusplus` macro.

Comment: I'm hoping that a practical implementation is good with the hint either before or after. Otherwise that's a drastic change.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The text above doesn't actually tell you that. But the other text in the standards ("iterator p is a hint pointing to where the insert should start to search" and "t is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to p"), or a little thought about how it must be implemented, imply that it probably is still amortized constant, just with a higher constant. (Basically, you have to do two fetches and compares per insert instead of one.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest two things:

- prefer `std::unordered_map` in this case, always inserting at one end is a worst-case scenario for red-black trees
- use a custom allocator if `new` proves to be a bother, from what you are talking about a pool allocation strategy could be used

Note that C++11 allows stateful allocators to be used, so it should be easy enough to provide an allocator that fits and have an embedded `std::vector<T>` inside and use it as a stack.

Answer (score 1):

Any suggestion is simply a suggestion, something to try and measure. We can't really tell you the most performant way to do insertion, you should measure for your own specific use case and see whats best.

If your map is compact and dense (almost all items from 0 - max key are occupied by real data) and the max key is low enough to be a reasonable array index you could switch to using a `std::vector<value>` and always inserting onto the end. Since its ever growing you'll occasionally need to reallocate the vector (typically this is when the vector doubles). This can be expensive, but generally insertion will be very cheap. You don't have to deal with the potential rebalancing of a binary tree and vector is extremely cache friendly for other purposes.

If your map's key space is not compact/dense and the max key is so large that its not a conceivable index into memory, then insertion with a hint is going to be your best bet.

If order doesn't matter, you can try [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). This is a hash table implementation. So insertion cost is going to relate to the quality and speed of the hash. It should be trivial and fast to take your 64 bit key and turn it into a size_t hash (size_t may even be 64 bits).

But don't have to take my word for it, measure it, and see for yourself...

Comment: Usually I'd say the same thing myself, but in this case the hint parameter was added to the standard interface for a reason.

Comment: My data is the opposite of what you call "dense". I have 2 million insertions (in 20 seconds) and the average number of elements in the container (map) is around 20. But the key (as I said) is ever increasing. What do you say? Map, with hint to the end? Or does it in my case a rebalancing of the tree too often?

Comment: @Frank I'd try an unordered_map if order doesn't matter. I'll also say that STL containers are fairly general purpose. In my experience, there are occasionally times when performance is so important that its worth writing a data structure bred for your very specific purpose. Of course then you can easily shoot yourself in the foot. As always measure and consider your options carefully.

Comment: @DougT. Okay, will give unordered_map a try. One question: `map` and `unordered_map` use internally the `new` operator to allocate memory for the new element. Can this be optimized a lot by using a constant size pool allocator?

Comment: Well, the usual *"don't think, measure!"*-answer becomes even more rubbish when the standard says *"if you insert it there, it's constant (even if amortized), otherwise logarithmic"*. But Ok, the rest of the answer is quite good -1/+1.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Actually, unless you get to huge N, there's not much difference between constant and logarithmic. And considering that N here (the size of the map at the time of each insertion) is "a couple handfuls" or "around 20", this is very definitely a case for "don't think, measure".

Answer (score 1):

I did some measurements since I came across this issue recently.

I have a big map, with lots of data, the data is rarely inserted, 99% of the time is just accessed and modified in place using references.
However, this data has to eventually be saved to disk and loaded back.
Solutions like "use a unordered map", seem a cheap fast way of doing it wrong, ordered map was the proper way for me, since data is ordered. Only issue was loading from file.

I wanted to know what is the real cost of this operation and how to speed it up, so, I measured:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

std::vector<int> amount = {100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 5000000};

int main()
{
  for(int j=0; j<amount.size(); j++) 
  {
    clock_t tStart = clock();

    std::map<int,int> mymap;
    for(int i=0; i<amount[j]; i++){
      mymap[i] = i;
    }

    printf("Time taken []: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart));
  }
  for(int j=0; j<amount.size(); j++) 
  {
    clock_t tStart = clock();

    std::map<int,int> mymap;
    mymap[0] = 0;
    auto it = mymap.begin();
    for(int i=1; i<amount[j]; i++){
      it = mymap.insert(it, std::pair<int,int>(i,i));
    }

    printf("Time taken insert end()-1: %.2fns\n", (double)(clock() - tStart));
  }
  for(int j=0; j<amount.size(); j++) 
  {
    clock_t tStart = clock();

    std::map<int,int> mymap;
    for(int i=1; i<amount[j]; i++){
      mymap.insert(mymap.end(), std::pair<int,int>(i,i));
    }

    printf("Time taken insert end(): %.2fns\n", (double)(clock() - tStart));
  }
  for(int j=0; j<amount.size(); j++) 
  {
    clock_t tStart = clock();

    std::map<int,int> mymap;
    for(int i=0; i<amount[j]; i++){
      mymap.insert(mymap.begin(), std::pair<int,int>(i,i));
    }

    printf("Time taken insert begin(): %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Time in ns
N       end()-1 end()   begin() []
100     12      8       22      12
1000    77      54      188     97
10000   763     532     2550    1174
100000  7609    6042    23612   17164
1000000 75561   62048   270476  272099
5000000 362463  306412  1827807 1687904
```

[image]
[image]

**Summary:**

- YES there is gain, huge gain, without any real drawback. Extremely better than an unordered map when data is ordered, extremely useful for the case of saving to a file a map and recreating it.
- Insert time if hint is correct is the same regardless of the number of elements. So there is no need to recur to a hashing unordered map to have constant time.
- Worst case it that you might loose some if your hint is the worst hint possible. I see no point any more to do inserts without a hint, specially if you have knowledge on where the data will be inserted. And most of the time you do.